# Get data from two databases

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I have two databases, one is on SQL Server and the other is on PostgreSQL.  Is there a way to join tables from these two database, or, if not possible, is there a way to pull from both databases and put the result in a temp table?

Thanks!

Comment: to pull records from anyone db- you can take a sql dump backup -just cross verify the syntaxes as per another db and run the dump against another db

Comment: Do you want to run the query in SQL Server or Postgres? You can create a linked server in SQL Server to Postgres as per the link below. But this runs out of steam eventually and you need to think of a better way, like replicating one database into another

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I want to run in SQL Server, but can't link server coz I only have read access.

Comment: If you only have read access you can try `OPENSROWSET`, but this is not a good long term solution

Answer (score 1):

**Foreign Data Wrapper**

PostgreSQL supports Foreign Data Wrappers, per the SQL standard. See [the wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers).

The easy way, use [FDW for SQL Server](https://github.com/tds-fdw/tds_fdw) and see remote SQL Server table like a local table.

Comment: What if I only have read access to the DBs?

Comment: both servers? you must need admin rights to create the fdw or the linked servers

Answer (score -1):

You could create link server, see below link for more details:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15